# Spring Cloud Config + HashiCorp Vault Cannot connect

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-config, hashicorp-vault

I have a Spring Cloud Config App set up, with an application.yml like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  profiles:
    active:
      - vault

cloud:
  config:
    server:
      vault:
        port: 8200
        host: http://127.0.0.1/
      #Local configuration: This locations can either of  classpath or locations in the filesystem.
      native:
        #geht von src/main/resources aus
        search-locations: classpath:/config
  vault:
    authentication: TOKEN
    token: vault-plaintext-root-token
    scheme: http
    port: 8200
    host: http://127.0.0.1/


server:
  port: 8071
```

Here is relevant parts of my POM:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

I have a hashcorp vault container running under localhost, which when I enter my token in the UI I can see the data (config) I want to download when I go here:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8200/ui/vault/secrets/licensing-service/show/dev
```

When I start up my Application I get this:

```
2023-01-02T12:51:16.450+01:00  WARN 25088 --- [(3)-192.168.0.8] o.s.c.c.s.c.ConfigServerHealthIndicator  : Health check failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:313) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:329) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:324) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils$ObjectFactoryDelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(AutowireUtils.java:289) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy112.getHeader(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.HttpRequestConfigTokenProvider.getToken(HttpRequestConfigTokenProvider.java:43) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.VaultEnvironmentRepository.getToken(VaultEnvironmentRepository.java:115) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.VaultEnvironmentRepository.read(VaultEnvironmentRepository.java:106) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractVaultEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractVaultEnvironmentRepository.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentRepository.java:30) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:134) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.VaultEnvironmentRepository$$SpringCGLIB$$0.findOne(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.lambda$findOne$3(ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:559) ~[micrometer-observation-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.findOne(ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:82) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.ConfigServerHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(ConfigServerHealthIndicator.java:77) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:41) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getLoggedHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:172) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:145) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:156) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:81) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:76) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:66) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:122) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:97) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1405) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:598) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:844) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:720) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

When I startup with native profile, I get no errors. When I try to access the config from another app (App on any port accesses my config server on 8071) I get no configs. In the console of my spring cloud config app it says this:

```
Error getting the Environment with name=licensing-service profiles=dev label=null includeOrigin=true

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing required header in HttpServletRequest: X-Config-Token
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.HttpRequestConfigTokenProvider.getToken(HttpRequestConfigTokenProvider.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.VaultEnvironmentRepository.getToken(VaultEnvironmentRepository.java:115) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.VaultEnvironmentRepository.read(VaultEnvironmentRepository.java:106) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractVaultEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractVaultEnvironmentRepository.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentRepository.java:30) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:134) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.VaultEnvironmentRepository$$SpringCGLIB$$0.findOne(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.lambda$findOne$3(ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:559) ~[micrometer-observation-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.findOne(ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:82) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.lambda$findOne$3(ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:559) ~[micrometer-observation-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.findOne(ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.getEnvironment(EnvironmentController.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.defaultLabelIncludeOrigin(EnvironmentController.java:113) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:482) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.defaultLabelIncludeOrigin(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1010) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:902) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

This just means there is a missing token. When I do this in my terminal:

```
curl -X "GET" "http://localhost:8071/licensing-service/dev" -H  "X-Config-Token: vault-plaintext-root-token"
```

I get no property Sources.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The First Error may be an indicator of what is happening but I can't see what's wrong tbh.

Answer (score 2):

In your configuration service have the following configuration in the `bootstrap.yml` file

```
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          host: 127.0.0.1
          port: 8200
          order: 1
          kv-version: 2
          authentication: TOKEN
          token: ${TOKEN}
          profile-separator: /

        git:
          default-label: ${GIT_LABEL}
          uri: ${CONFIG_REPO_URL}
          username: ${CONFIG_REPO_USERNAME}
          password: ${CONFIG_REPO_PASSWORD}
          ignore-local-ssh-settings: true
          skip-ssl-validation: true
          order: 2
  profiles:
    active: git, vault
```

You also need to set both profile as active

In your other service, (the one that should fetch its configuration from the configuration service) add the following dependencies

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

Also you need to make sure that in your vault service your secrets are under the `/secret` directory

i.e `/secret/my-service/profile`

The error that is occurring might still happen, but it will not shutdown the application and the application will still work normally.

now if you navigate to

`http://localhost:8888/my-service/profile` (assuming that the config service is on 8888)

you will have the following result

```
{
   "name":"my-service",
   "profiles":[
      "profile"
   ],
   "label":null,
   "version":null,
   "state":null,
   "propertySources":[
      {
         "name":"vault:my-service/profile",
         "source":{
            "user.password":"secret-value",
            "user.username":"secret-value"
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"<git-url-loocation>",
         "source":{
            "server.port":8079
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Notice how under `propertySources` there is two types, the one coming from the vault, and the other properties coming from a github repo or in your case a file system.